# CSS: element goes on top, though supposed to be in bottom

Tags: html, css

The element "#bottom-nav" goes on top. 
I've just created this on CSS-board, there you can check HTML and CSS

[CSS-desk](http://cssdesk.com/PB2cY)

It is last on the page and has 'margin_top' property.

P.S. element is visible only if you resize result window to full screen

Answer (score 2):

Change `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;`

`absolute` does what it means. It fixes it to the position. Other relative elements, like your bottom nav will simply ignore any CSS element that is marked as `absolute`.

Comment: I upvoted, but that is not full solution. Problem is that when I look the page content via Chrome, it shows  `.all_links` height as without inner table, so it higlights links, but not the table, when I choose element, although table is inside this div.

Comment: So now bottom_nav is not higher, but in the middle of .all_links

Answer (score -1):

Set `#bottom-nav` to `position:absolute` and `bottom:0` with `width:100%`. You'll need to adjust your margin and/or padding.